# Delete text before "=" sign in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to delete a text before "=" in notepad ++.

Example

```
'abc = def'
'123 = 456'
```

Output Should be

```
'def'
'456'
```

Comment: Not tried, looking for answer

Comment: Do you need a regex for that? I'd just use column mode, highlight, and delete.

Comment: some lines of text are big and some lines of text are small, so i cannot use column mode

Comment: Another post where you can see a [detailed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20286068/628006)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open replace with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
Select search mode = regular expression

Enter this line in "Find what"

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+=[ ]*
```

Make sure "Replace with" is empty

Click Replace All.

Comment: Got one more  regex `.*= ` this also works

Comment: That's a little too simple for your own example, as it will also delete the first quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

1. replace `=` with `\n=` (regular expression on)
2. Find all `=`, mark all, copy bookmarked lines, insert into a new document
3. replace `=` to `'`